# Why would changing the ResultSetType from TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE to TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY change the results of an SQL Query?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw, isolation-level

During a project, we discovered that some of the SQL statements we were executing (but not all of them) were returning different results in our Java application vs. when they were run in a stand-alone SQL IDE like Aquadata or Toad. This uses a DB2 database.

I can't show actual data (contains PHI) but I'll mock up an example to give you a sense of what was happening:

AquaData results (believed via other means to be correct/valid):

```
 Name         | ID            | Count
--------------|---------------|---------------
 Alexander    | 12345         | 15
 Debra        | 23456         | 34
 Igor         | 54321         | 3
 Francesca    | 34567         | 108
```

Java Results (believed via other means to be incorrect/invalid):

```
 Name         | ID            | Count
--------------|---------------|---------------
 Alexander    | 12345         | 15
 Debra        | 23456         | 33
 Igor         | 54321         | 3
```

So a few things stand out:

- One of the counts (but not all of them) is immediately incorrect (went from 34 to 33)
- One of the rows is absent entirely

The `Count` row is calculated by, as the name implies, counting other elements within the SQL query, as per a `COUNT(*)` statement.

However, when we were digging into our code, we discovered that we could get the Java results to *exactly match the other results* by changing how we created a `PreparedStatement` object.

Old Version (Produced incorrect results):

```
try (PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)){
```

New Version (Produced correct results):

```
try (PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
```

This simple change caused the Java Result Set to exactly match the AquaData (and other methods) Result Set. Digging into the Java documentation, it appears the only meaningful change is that the `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` parameter is instead `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` in the default parameters; the `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` parameter is not changed in the default parameters.

Why would this have such a substantial result on our results? As best as we know, the data underlying this query is not changing between (or during) executions of this code, so changing the scroll type shouldn't have an effect on the result set. So why else might we expect this kind of change to have such a substantial impact on our results?

---

Additional info:

DB2 Platform: Linux/Unix/Windows
DB2 version*: `10050700 3/22/2016 1:56:57 PM    s151221` ( Db2-LUW v10.5.0.7 )

JDBC Vendor: IBM
JDBC Version: 3.69.24

Java Vendor: IBM
Java Version: IBM 32-bit SDK for Windows, Java Technology Edition, Version 7

<sup>* Acquired by executing `select versionnumber, version_timestamp, versionbuildlevel from sysibm.sysversions order by 2 desc`.</sup>

Comment: If it's provably correct that the underlying data is *not* changing, then the behaviour is defective. Equally if *any* of the data (e.g. in MQTs or Nickname objects, or metadata) is changing then the behaviour may be correct. You write that *some* queries (but not all) are impacted, so use that to narrow down the possibilities. Sometimes, things are not what they appear, and sometimes you think you are comparing like for like but you are not. If you lack the required forensic diagnostics skills, open a ticket with IBM Db2 support. It may take longer than skilled on-site problem-determination.

Answer (score 0):

TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE - ...not sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the ResultSet.  Meaning that the application or server are free to prefetch data without regard to whether the data might change by the time the application uses it.

TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY - ...object whose cursor may move only forward.  But the rows are retrieved as they are used.

CONCUR_READ_ONLY - ...that your ResultSet object may NOT be updated.  Meaning locks can be released immediately.

In the Insensitive case you end up with a "dirty-read" locking mechanism that may produce a different result set if the table is being updated by another application at the same time.

I am hoping that your "wrong" and "correct" cases are always changing and that it is not consistently wrong with the exact same answer every time.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to answer, but unfortunately, the wrong and correct cases *are* pretty consistently wrong and correct. The data isn't changing between executions, and I've been able to "toggle" back and forth between each case to verify that this change to the prepared statement is causing the change in behavior.

Comment: The difference might be due to uncommitted changes. Add option " with ur " to sql and run it in aquadata. If the issue is due to uncommited data, results should match with Java Result set (TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE)

Comment: @Xirema You should open a Case with IBM Support.